# Vertically Align and match biggest height li element with all others.

Tags: css

I got List items going in red and i want them to be the same height as the biggest height in the list elements which right now are the crains images. Right now the code look likes this. I also want them to be centered so the are all aligned vertically.

```
<ul class="press_list">
 <li><img src=""/></li>
</ul>
```

image http://tinypic.com/r/wlad8o/8

You can see all the red boxes don't match up in height and the images aren't vertically centered. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To have the elements vertical aligned you have to set them as `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block;` and declare them width `vertical-align: middle;` in your css file. They will align with the `line-height` that is declared there, a trick to center elements is to declare the `font-size` equal as the `height` and give it the `vertical-align: middle;` property, that way the `line-height` will be all the `height` and elements will be aligned exactly in the middle.

I made an example but instead of using images I am setting different heights for the elements. You will see how, at first, they have different widths and heights but after the js is runned they get the same height as the maximun one and are also vertical aligned. Try fist commenting the js code so you see the elements at the beginning, then try it again with the js and you will see how they get the same height.

Take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/p2nbuux7/15/

Se where I set the heights:

see that I initialize the max_height variable in -1 just in case.

```
var max_height = -1;
```

And use jQuery "each" function to get the maximun height

```
$('.press_list').find('li').each(function(){
    // Code here
});
```